# What are the lightest hypothesis needed to be able to get the limit inside the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Riemann integrable functions.

What are the lightest conditions on $f_n$ to guarantee the following?

$$
\lim_n \int_a^b f_n\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^b \lim_n f_n \, \mathrm dx
$$

I'm aware of dominated convergence theorem, but are there lighter sufficient conditions for the above to hold? Maybe in some special cases...

Comment: If there were "lightest hypotheses," there would be a theorem called "the best theorem of all in bringing the limit inside the integral".

Answer (score 1):

Another criterium is Arzelà's bounded convergence theorem. If $f_n\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ are Riemann integrable such that

1. $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a Riemann integrable function $f$
2. $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded

Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf_n=\int_a^bf.
$$

Observe that the integrability of the limit is one of the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a criterion goes by the name of Uniform Convergence Theorem:

If the sequence $\{f_{n} \}$ of integrable functions converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $f$, then $f$ is integrable and $\int_{a}^{b} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_{n}$.

Comment: I thought of that as a stronger requirement.

Comment: You did not give a precise definition of what would constitute a weaker requirement.